# Clear multi select (react-select)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I use https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select.

My Component sample:
**selectedOptions**: []
In first load component multi select is empty. When i select some values I have values which i write to **selectedOptions**. In this case it works correctly.
But when I clear **selectedOptions** view doesnt update.

**There are example** https://codesandbox.io/s/xovn7n2lz4

```
<Select
            defaultValue={selectedOptions}
            isMulti={isMulti}
            onChange={onChange}
            options={options}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            styles={colourStyles}
            theme={(theme) => ({
                ...theme,
                position: 'static',
                borderRadius: 0,
                colors: {
                    ...theme.colors,
                    primary25: darkTheme.colors.hoverColor,
                    primary: darkTheme.colors.hoverColor,
                    neutral0: normalElemColor,
                    neutral80: standardFontColor,
                },
                spacing: {
                    ...theme.spacing,
                    controlHeight: 24,
                    baseUnit: 1
                }
            })}
        />
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show us you `onChange` function ? thank you

Comment: Yes, of course, @Laura
https://codesandbox.io/s/xovn7n2lz4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using uncontrolled input.

Change

```
 <Select isMulti
          defaultValue={selectedOptions}         
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
          name="color"
          options={colourOptions}
        />
```

To

```
<Select
          isMulti
          defaultValue={selectedOptions}
          value={selectedOptions}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
          name="color"
          options={colourOptions}
        />
```

You have defined onchange but didn't provide any value.
I suggest you to react [controlled vs uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqnz9qn51z)